# how i can get product id on cj dropshipping?

Tags: dropshipping

I would like to know how to get the product id on CJ dropshipping. I am having difficulty understanding what the product id number is that I have to import into my dropshipping store via CJdropshipping. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at their CJ developers API -

https://developers.cjdropshipping.com/cj/shop-products.html#list-products